# How to get the size of nasm-assembled instructions in boot sector?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, boot

I am assembling a program with nasm to fit in the boot sector (512 bytes max).

e.g. `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin`

The last two lines of the program pad the remaining space with 0 and add the magic bytes:

```
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; Pad the remaining of the first 510 bytes with 0
dw 0xaa55               ; Magic bytes required at end of boot sector
```

The outputted `boot.bin` file is always 512 bytes (expected), so I cannot trivially look at the size of `boot.bin` to get the size of the meaningful (non-padding and non-magic bytes) instructions.

I imagine it would work to print `($-$$)` at assembly time (similar to `#warning` or `#pragma message` for gcc), but I cannot find any way to print at nasm assembly time.

Is there a clean or straightforward way to know the size of the instructions before padding?

It would be nice to avoid hacky methods like printing at runtime or searching backwards through `boot.bin` looking for a non-zero value.

Comment: Just ask for a listing using `-l`. Or pad the file outside of nasm using your build environment.

Comment: The comment by @Jester is the best answer. I used `-l listing.txt` to generate a listing file. In the listing file, it is plain to see the size of the meaningful instructions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%assign` to evaluate a numeric expression at assemble time. (Each assembly pass also uses the preprocessor. This is how you can do limited arithmetic on labels using the preprocessor.) Then [use `%warning` to display an assemble time message](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.9). The only downside is that it'll display "as a warning", but it is assembly time output. Quoting the manual:

> [...] %warning issues a warning, but allows assembly to continue:
>
> [...]
>
> It is optional for the message string after %error, %warning or %fatal to be quoted. If it is *not*, then single-line macros are expanded in it, which can be used to display more information to the user.

In [my boot sector loaders](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldosboot/file/9b4630a8bb8a/boot.asm#l1587) I do this:

```
available:
    _fill 508,38,start

signatures:
    dw 0
; 2-byte magic bootsector signature
    dw 0AA55h

%assign num signatures-available
%assign fatbits 12
%if _FAT16
 %assign fatbits 16
%endif
%warning FAT%[fatbits]: num bytes still available.
%endif

end:
```

`_fill` is from [the macro collection](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/file/ede277bd4d21/lmacros1.mac#l811). Refer to [my question about the zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145890/does-any-fat-fs-driver-want-bytes-508-and-509-of-the-boot-sector-to-be-zero/) for the meaning of the first `dw` here.

Example output:

```
boot.asm:1600: warning: FAT12: 10 bytes still available. [-w+user]
```

Comment: That's interesting.  From the name, I would have expected that a "preprocessor directive" would execute on an earlier pass, before any assembly was done or any addresses were computed, and so I wouldn't have guessed that this would work.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I use this integrated preprocessor scheme's features basically in any nontrivial program. Which is the reason you can't do `nasm -E` (preprocess only) with any of my sources. Cue `error: symbol references not supported in preprocess-only mode`

Answer (score 3):

You could put a label before the padding and do `size: dw $-$$` to store a size in the bootloader that you could look at in an asm listing or hexdump.  But that takes up 2 bytes.

`nasm -fbin foo.asm -l /dev/stdout | less` will display a **listing** of address | hexdump | source line, making it very easy to see where the `time ... db 0` starts, and to the integer you put into the `dw`.  You can see an example of that format in [a code-golf answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132719/the-chroma-key-to-success/132757#132757) for example.

---

Or you can simply comment out the `times 510 - ($-$$) db 0` / `dw 0xaa55` padding and look at the file size!

If you're close to the limit, leave it commented out while optimizing for code size until you have something you think should fit and work.

Comment: Is there really nothing comparable to MASM's `ECHO $`? Similar to defining `lblBEGIN EQU $` at the beginning and `ECHO $-lblBEGIN` at the end?

Comment: @zx485: Like a CPP `#warn` equivalent for making the assembler itself do I/O at assemble time?  Not that I know of; nasm keeps it simple.  If you assemble into a `.o` or `.obj` with `-felf32` (or something16?) you could get symbol metadata with `nm`.

Comment: Well, ok. But I don't get the "NASM keeps it simple", because I wouldn't consider an _assemble-time output_-function to be complicated ;-) However, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @zx485: NASM's preprocessor does have a `%warning` directive, but preprocessing happens before assembling so you can't can't warn about things that can't be known until after it's too late.

Comment: @Brendan: Wrong, refer to my answer. `%warning` can use scalar numbers calculated by the assembler part. This is because the preprocessor is run together with the assembler for each pass. This is hinted at [in the manual](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.9) a bit: "`%error` and `%warning` are issued only on the final assembly pass." That is they are issued only on the final pass, but are processed or handled (skipped) by the preprocessor on every pass.

Comment: @ecm: What you've overlooked is that you need something to decide if the warning should/shouldn't be used (e.g. like `%if $$-$ < 100` then `%warning "Less than 100 bytes free now!"` then `%endif`).

Comment: @Brendan: You can do that no problem. Though it is `$ - $$` not the other way around. And you want `510 - ($ - $$)`, just `$ - $$` gives amount of bytes assembled into the current section yet. However, I'm reading the question as wanting an unconditional display.

Comment: @ecm: You can't display a number inside a warning (e.g. `%assign a $-$$` then `%warning Bytes = %a` will not work - it must be a plain string).

Comment: @Brendan: Please try it before claiming it doesn't work. I've been using this mechanism as specified in my answer for more than 8 years now. Any modern NASM supports it. As my quote of the manual lists, you can do `%assign a $ - $$` then `%warning The number is a` to have NASM expand the `a` define in the message.

Comment: @ecm: Ah, sorry. I did try it (but tried it "wrong", without the `%[ ]` to get it to expand).

Comment: @Brendan: The macro indirection with `%[...]` is only needed for embedding the result into another word. As in my answer, `num` is just a bare word in the `%warning` and is expanded to the define's value.

Comment: @zx485: turns out I was wrong, NASM's `%warning` *can* reference stuff like symbol offsets; see @ecm's answer.  (By simple, I didn't mean really hard to implement, I meant weird from a language-design POV, like it makes it into a scripting language that can do I/O to the terminal running the assembler.)